# How to upload nodejs project or install nodejs and npm modules on live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, server

I've made a real time chat application with node and socket io and it is running well in my local machine. But its time to run it on my live windows server. I can't understand to how set it up there. Do I need to upload the files to the server or I've to install node js and npm modules in the server and then upload the files. And how I can do these? How I'll run the command prompt as we do in local machine like **node chat.js**  ? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you selected in any Hosting Service Provider? Like aws/heroku/openshift ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deployment client like [Capistrano](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-with-capistrano) or you can just upload your source files then run npm install (assuming your have node installed) followed by your commands to bring up the server. I'd suggest using a framework like meteor or sails to make deployment easier. Or using a cloud solution like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins) for deploying your app to server. Running bash commands and setting builds are much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

1. Download and install NodeJS, NPM ([here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/))
2. You need to establish a simple way to move your files to the remote server. Since you can run your code and do the development at your local machine, I recommend you to use github for this purpose. Set up a repository and clone it at your remote server. Then, you can always push and pull your changes using git.
3. You need to establish a simple way to run your code at the remote server. Since you use Windows, I recommend you to create a `.bat` file that does all the preparations and runs your code. In the simplest case, it would contain `node path\to\project\chat.js`. Then, run this file using a console. If you're going to use github, you probably should include this `.bat` file to your repository.

Good luck!